# express session is different for different routes, node and react

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, single-page-application, passport-local

My issue is that the session IDs differ when I 'POST' a log in, to when I 'GET' after being logged in.
[image: differing session ids for the same username & pass]
I am running React as a SPA on the front end with react router handling all other urls as sub routes of '/'. The front end has a proxy to the backend in package.json "proxy":"http://localhost:5000" 
I plan to keep track of a users state by verifying that they are in session, and using React Context. BUT, I cannot seem to get past this hurdle. I have read EVERY related stack overflow post (multiple times) similar to this scenario, but to no avail...

Here is my front end making the get request:

```
import './App.css';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

const makeGet = () => {
  let userData = { username: 'johnson72', password: 'a' }
  axios.get('/api/dashboard')
    .then((res) => console.log(res.status))
    .catch((err) => err.response.status === 500 ? navigate('/login', { replace: true }) && console.log('8err', err) : console.log(err))
}

const loginPost = () => {
  let userData = { username: 'johnson72', password: 'a' }
  axios.post('/login', userData, {withCredentials: true, credentials: 'include'})
    .then((res) => console.log(res.status))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}

const handleGet = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  makeGet();
}
const handleLogin = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  loginPost();
}
  return (
    <>
    <div className="App">
      <div className='jumbotron-fluid d-flex align-items-center' style={{backgroundColor:'pink', height:'15rem'}}>
          <div className='container'>
            <Navbar />
            <div className='row'>
              <h3>{data?.username ? 'Hello ' + data?.username + ' ' + data?.email + '!' : ''}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <Outlet />
    </div>
    <Button variant='dark' onClick={handleGet}>Get</Button>
    <Button variant='dark' onClick={loginPost}>Login</Button>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Here is my backend receiving the get request

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import routes from './routes/userRoutes';
import passport from 'passport'
import { User } from './datamodels/schema';
import session from 'express-session'
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';


const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test5', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

app.use(express.json());
// app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(session({ 
    secret: "cats",
    // cookie: { maxAge: 600000 },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser);

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',{failureMessage: true}), (req, res) => {
    console.log('you have hit the login route');
    console.log('req is auth ', req.isAuthenticated());
    console.log(req.user.username);
    console.log(req.session);
    console.log(req.session.id);
    
})
app.get('/api/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    // console.log('req is auth api / dashboard ', req.isAuthenticated());
    console.log('session id from api dash ', req.session.id);
})

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
        console.log(`User Is Logged In!`)
        return next();
    }
    res.sendStatus(500)
}

routes(app); // chained route handler 
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening @ ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: Try adding the `withCredentials` option to `axios.get('/api/dashboard')`.

Comment: @ jfriend00 , I have tried it how you mentioned, like this:
const makeGet = () => {
  let userData = { username: 'johnson72', password: 'a' }
  axios.get('/api/dashboard', { withCredentials: true })
    .then((res) => console.log(res.status))
    .catch((err) => err.response.status === 500 ? navigate('/login', { replace: true }) && console.log('8err', err) : console.log(err))
}
I have also tried it with passing the username and pass object before the withCredentials. I have also tried it with credentials: 'include'
I even set the default above: axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

Comment: I'd suggest you create a middleware on your server that logs the express-session cookie as your FIRST middleware.  You need to be able to see exactly when the session cookie is and isn't being sent by the client.  That's the first point of debugging session issues to make sure the right session cookie is being sent to the server.  You can also learn by looking at each client request in the Chrome debugger (network tab) and examining exactly what cookies are sent with each request.

Comment: I have been exploring based on your advice, and have noticed that so far, there are no cookies in the browser, from either of my front end requests: POST or GET. I am in the process of getting to the bottom of the issue, and will let you know what the resolve is.